# Binding SelectedItem from CollectionView

Tags: c#, mvvm, xamarin.forms, prism

I'm developing my frist app on xamarin-forms, using XamarinForms v4.2, Prism.Dryloc v7.2 and Refit.

I have 3 collectionview on my MenuPage

1. Food
2. Drinks
3. Cart

A web service fills the first two and they work great, I need to select one of each one and I'm trying to binding the selected items to the Cart collection, I'm debugging to understand how it works but at the moment of selection this appear on my Debug Console:
 `"[0:] Binding: KioscoColab.Models.Menu can not be converted to type 'System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection'1[KioscoColab.Models.Menu]`

Here is my code:

ViewModel

```
...

ObservableCollection<Menu> _food;
ObservableCollection<Menu> _drinks;
ObservableCollection<Menu> _cart;

public ObservableCollection<Menu> Food
{
     get => _food;
     set => SetProperty(ref _food, value);
}

public ObservableCollection<Menu> Drinks
{
     get => _drinks;
     set => SetProperty(ref _drinks, value);
}

public ObservableCollection<Menu> Cart
{
     get => _cart;
     set => SetProperty(ref _cart, value);
}

...
public async Task LoadMenu()
{
     //Here is my logic for the web service
     ...
     Food = new ObservableCollection<Menu>(food.Content);
     Drinks = new ObservableCollection<Menu>(drinks.Content);
     Cart = new ObservableCollection<Menu>();
}
...
```

XamlPage

```
<!--  CollectionView Food-->
<CollectionView
            Grid.Row="1"
            Grid.Column="0"
            Margin="5"
            ItemsSource="{Binding Food}"
            SelectedItem="{Binding Cart, Mode=TwoWay}"
            SelectionMode="Single"
            VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Always">
            <CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
                <GridItemsLayout Orientation="Vertical" />
            </CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
            <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid Margin="5">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Label
                            Grid.Column="0"
                            FontSize="Medium"
                            Text="{Binding Description}"
                            VerticalOptions="Center" />
                        <Label
                            Grid.Column="1"
                            FontSize="Medium"
                            HorizontalTextAlignment="End"
                            Text="{Binding Price, StringFormat='{0:C}'}"
                            VerticalOptions="Center" />
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        </CollectionView>


<!--  CollectionView Cart  -->
<CollectionView
            Grid.Row="1"
            Grid.Column="1"
            Margin="5"
            ItemsSource="{Binding Cart}"
            VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Always">            
            <CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
                <GridItemsLayout Orientation="Vertical" Span="2" />
            </CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
            <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid Margin="5">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="20" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Label
                            Grid.Column="0"
                            FontSize="18"
                            Text="{Binding Description}"
                            VerticalOptions="Center" />
                        <Label
                            Grid.Column="1"
                            FontSize="18"
                            Text="{Binding Price}"
                            VerticalOptions="End" />
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        </CollectionView>
```

How can I make the cast? Or what should I do?

Comment: you're trying to bind SelectedItem (which is ONE item) to Cart, which is a Collection.  That just won't work.  I don't think you're going to be able to do this purely with bindings - you probably need event handlers or commands on your first two CollectionViews that will update the Cart ObservableCollection

Comment: and you don't want (public) setters on observable collections, btw

Comment: @Haukinger If I change them to private my xaml can't found the property

Comment: @Jason You're right, I didn't pay attention to "SelectedItem" I was a little frustrated. I'll investigate about event handlers, thx a lot.